# Some of my Python package does not work in OSX console

Tags: python, macos, numpy, matplotlib, ipython

I am new in Python. I have trouble in my OSX.

My Python version

```
python --version
Python 2.7.8
```

My ipython version

```
IPython 2.3.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
```

My OSX version

```
Yosemit 10.10.1
```

I am confused because some of my Python lib work well in console such as when I tried to import urllib but some of my Python libs also does not work in console. But all of my python packages work well in ipython.

When I tried in my console

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
>>> import urllib
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named matplotlib
>>>
```

When I tried in my ipython console

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: import urllib

In [3]: import matplotlib

In [4]:
```

Result of `which python`

```
users-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ which python
python is /opt/local/bin/python
python is /usr/local/bin/python
python is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
python is /usr/local/bin/python
python is /usr/bin/python
python is /usr/local/bin/python


users-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ which -a ipython
ipython is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/ipython
```

Comment: It will depend how you installed things. Suspect that when you type "python" alone, you are getting the system version, not your user version. Check your PATH and "which python".

Comment: The modules you are trying to import are not in your Python path. You need to add the path where you installed numpy and matplotlib to your Python path. Did you install a distribution of Python like Anaconda or Enthought? How did you install these modules? Type `which python` to see which Python on your system you are using.

Comment: Probably the easiest way to solve this is to install ipython for your current python version. `python -m pip install ipython` should do the trick. If it does not, please add `which -a ipython` and `which -a python` to your question.

Comment: @ChrisP @mdurant I've edit my question with `which python` result, can you help me to solve this problem? thank :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to export python site packages PATH in your console

```
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
```

Another way, add that path to .bash_profile file in your home directory. For more details read [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/using/mac.html).